# ros2_control Odometery Data Publication Frequency Discrepancy

Tags: ros2, odometry, ros-control, diff-drive-controller, frequency

I am using ros2_control framework to control the motor wheel of my robot and to publish odometry data. However, I have encountered an unusual issue where the odometry data is being published at only half the specified frequency as set in the publish_rate parameter in the ros2_control configuration file. For instance, when I set the publish_rate to 50, upon checking the odometery data, it is only being published at 25. Similarly, when I set the publish_rate to 80, I am observing a publication rate of only 40. Could you please review the attached configuration file to investigate this matter?

````
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100 # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    diffbot_base_controller:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

diffbot_base_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    left_wheel_names: ["left_wheel_joint"]
    right_wheel_names: ["right_wheel_joint"]

    wheel_separation: 0.4582
    #wheels_per_side: 1  # actually 2, but both are controlled by 1 signal
    wheel_radius: 0.081

    wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
    left_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
    right_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0

    publish_rate: 80.0
    odom_frame_id: odom
    base_frame_id: base_link
    pose_covariance_diagonal : [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01] #[0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01] #[0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01]

    open_loop: false #true
    enable_odom_tf: true #true

    cmd_vel_timeout: 0.5
    #publish_limited_velocity: true
    use_stamped_vel: false
    #velocity_rolling_window_size: 10

    # Velocity and acceleration limits
    # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
    linear.x.has_velocity_limits: true
    linear.x.has_acceleration_limits: true
    linear.x.has_jerk_limits: false
    linear.x.max_velocity: 1.0
    linear.x.min_velocity: -1.0
    linear.x.max_acceleration: 1.0
    linear.x.max_jerk: 0.0
    linear.x.min_jerk: 0.0

    angular.z.has_velocity_limits: true
    angular.z.has_acceleration_limits: true
    angular.z.has_jerk_limits: false
    angular.z.max_velocity: 1.0
    angular.z.min_velocity: -1.0
    angular.z.max_acceleration: 1.0
    angular.z.min_acceleration: -1.0
    angular.z.max_jerk: 0.0
    angular.z.min_jerk: 0.0 ```
````

Comment: Can you please provide some more information, e.g. ROS 2 version and if you are using simulation (which one) or real robot (which hardware interface, are you using ros2_control_node?)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using the ROS 2 'Humble' version with a physical robot, and yes, I am utilizing the 'ros2_control_node'.

Comment: do you use a public ros2_control hardware component for your robot, or have you written a custom one? At which rate does the joint_state_publisher publish /joint_state topic?

Comment: Yes, I am utilizing the public hardware interface. However, I have created my own custom functions which are used inside the 'read', 'write', and 'on_init' functions of the ROS 2 control hardware interface class. Additionally, the frequency of the '/joint_state' topic is 100 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed with rolling already, see [this PR](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/pull/644). I requested a backport to humble now, but this can take a while to get synced and released. In the meantime, you can use [this branch](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/pull/777) and compile it from source.